# How to change Date & Time format with Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, configuration, time, date

I'm working with Lubuntu.

The system information says: 
Release: Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid)
GNOME: 3.14.1
Kernel: 3.19.0-23-generic

My problem is about I've been reading all the questions about this issue and I tried all the "solutions", BUT... Nothing is happening!!!

Even the Language support menu shows me the right date and time format, I can't get it from LibreOffice or other software.

My local date and time should be: Viernes, 24 de Julio de 2015. 14:18 Hr.

What I get from the software is: 24/07/15 (not time).

It is the same with the file directory "explorer" and the date and time of each file.

How can I change it? ???

Greetings!!!

Juan

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple to understand "How To" that is posted in Lubuntu Community Help wiki.  The lubuntu date / time display is very adaptable. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/CustomizingTheClock